# Science fiction story about an intelligent man whose mind was uploaded into a computer to solve future problems

Tags: story-identification, mind-uploading

I read this not much more than 10 years ago, but it might be much older.

The man was not  “super-intelligent”, just someone who, through his faculty of analysis and/or intuition and/or general wisdom, had proven that his advices were usually excellent. When he was in danger of dying, his friends were loath to lose his qualities, and uploaded his mind into a computer, IIRC. He **might** have been put in suspended animation, but I think rather the computer thing. At some point a crisis happens and they turn the computer on (or revive him?), tell him about the situation, listen to his advice then turn the computer off (or put him back in suspended animation?).

It is all that I remember. It might have been the main theme of a rather short fiction, or just one scene (or maybe several similar scenes) in a full novel.

Now contrary to apparences this is **not** a duplicate of

[Science fiction story about an intelligent man put in suspended animation to solve future problems](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/208248/science-fiction-story-about-an-intelligent-man-put-in-suspended-animation-to-sol)

though of course it is this question that reminded me of my story.
Indeed the latter does not even have an answer accepted by the OP, though it is most probable that Dinae’s answer “The Sleeping God” is the correct one **there**. (So I granted her my bounty before it expired).

But it is **not** my story. The “intelligent man” is human. While he was still living “normally”, he belonged to the same community as the people who consult him later, the oldest ones knew him personally when they were younger, or at least heard of him first-hand from their parents. He is not “omniscient and omnipotent, of immense size and gigantic capabilities” only a very bright “normal” person.

Also there are no “morons” about. Those who consult him are clever, they just realise his advices are sound and want him to add his mind to theirs, in an situation of crisis. So not “The Marching Morons”.

Also he is **definitely** not Hari Seldon. His revivals are **not** prerecorded holograms. The people who ask him for advice actually tell him of the exact details of the current situation for him to evaluate.

It is also not “The Swarm”, where the hive-mind is not **human**, when he is, or at least was. But it might still be some other book in Bruce Sterling’s “Shapers/Mechanists” Universe. I feel some, how should I say, “taste” of this universe. But this is just a kind of subliminal feeling that I get, please do not restrict yourself to Bruce Sterling !

Comment: Regardless of what your question or answer might be, you've grossly mischaracterized "The Marching Morons".

Comment: I haven't read this book. I just saw this sentence **"a world mainly full of morons ruled by an intelligent elite.**' in Mohiri's answer to the other question. In my story, the society is similar to ours. Some people are more clever than others, and there must be a few "morons", people who are intellectually disabled. But there is no strong distinction between a majority of "morons" and an intelligent "elite". If there is a mischaracterisation, it is Mohiri's, not mine.

Comment: http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/51233

Comment: @Spencer Thanks a lot for the link. I've put in on my reading list. But anyway lots of details of Mohiri's description did not fit my memory.

Comment: There are probably quite a few novels that play on similar ideas, however one that I read at around the time you mention is [The Last Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Theorem)...

Comment: The Wikipedia page you link to says Subramanian (and his wife, but I was thinking of a man) is indeed "uploaded to cyberspace", but is is not sais that he is inactive most of the time and only activated when his advice is needed. I'll try to find a more detailed plot.

Comment: @Alfred Yes I tried to find a copy of the last chapter to confirm some of your details but was unsuccessful. It was a bit of a long shot...

Comment: @AdamJLimbert I found a copy of "The Last Theorem" Subramanian does not die, to be uploaded, until the very last chapter. They don't ask any question to him after he is uploaded. So this is not my story. Thanks anyway. It is now too late for my bounty, but I am still watching this thread in case an answer is proposed.

Comment: It was a good try, though. Subramanian was certainly an extremely clever person (based on Ramanujan), but was still a normal human being, not an alien with huge powers like Nagha from "The Sleeping God". Not far, but not the one.